# Программа работает правильно с 2-3 попытки (потоки). - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, многопоточность, mutex, двусвязный-список

Задача: используя двусвязный список, вывести на экран числа от 1 до 100 в порядке возрастания через 2 потока: первый добавляет в список нечетное число, второй добавляет четное число.

Когда я запускаю проект VS2017 и запускаю программу, программа выводит числа в порядке сначала ВСЕ нечетные, потом ВСЕ четные. Второй запуск - тот же самый результат. Третий, четвертый и т.д. - программа работает нормально, т.е. выводит числа по порядку. Как объяснить такое поведение?

Вот код:

```
class Program
{
    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(AddOdd);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(AddEven);

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();

        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join();
        foreach (Node node in List.GetArray())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
        }
    }

    static void AddEven()
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                mutex.WaitOne();
                List.Add(i);
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }

    static void AddOdd()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                mutex.WaitOne();
                List.Add(i);
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }
}

class List
{
    static int counter = 0;
    public static Node First { get; set; }
    public static Node Last { get; set; }

    public static void Add(int value)
    {
        if (First == null)
        {
            Last = First = new Node(value, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            Node node = new Node(value, Last, null);
            Last.Next = node;
            Last = node;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    public static Node[] GetArray()
    {
        Node[] nodes = new Node[counter];
        Node currentNode = First;
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            nodes[i] = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode.Next;
        }

        return nodes;
    }
}

class Node
{
    public Node Next { get; set; }
    public Node Previous { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Node(int value, Node prev, Node next)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Next = next;
        this.Previous = prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTBLEGOPeOo) есть очень хороший видео урок про потоки. Разжёвано как в детском садике. Проще объяснить думаю не получится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что потоки созданы для того, чтобы работать параллельно. Операции в потоках не обязаны выполняться по одной из каждого по очереди. В данном случае первый поток в нескольких запусках вашей программы успевал отработать полностью до того, как стартовал второй поток. По этому сначала в списке были все нечетные числа, а за ними все четные. Теоретически могло быть и наоборот.

Например, если вы искусственно замедлите потоки, в цикл каждого потока добавите вызов

```
Thread.Sleep(100)
```

то вы увидите, что результаты в списке оказались почти в правильном порядке.
Если в первом потоке изменить задержку на 50 миллисекунд, то нечетные числа в списке будут возрастать быстрее и закончатся примерно там, где четные дойдут до 50, потому что поток, выводящий нечетные числа, работает вдвое быстрее. Но раз от раза чередование чисел, выдаваемых потоками, может меняться, потому что они выполняются независимо друг от друга, и на скорость их выполнения могут влиять разные факторы (количество и загруженность ядер в вашем компьютере, работа менеджера потокв .NET и т.п.)